# Haskell assignment type

Tags: haskell

From the haskell.org website: every expression has a type. So what is the type of

```hs
main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"
```

I would like to know not what the type of `main` is, but what the type of the whole line is. Also, is it possible to get this type somehow in ghci? I tried

```hs
:t (main = putStrLn "Hello, World!")
```

but this does not work.

Comment: This *has* no type. This is not an assignment, this is a declaration, and a declaration is *not* an expression.

Comment: ...and the claim "every expression has a type" isn't even true; for example `True ++ ()` is ill-typed (it is an expression, but has no type), and `x ++ y` is ill-scoped (it is an expression, but refers to unbound variables, so its type can't be known (yet)). The website should probably be corrected to be a bit more precise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> every expression has a type.

That is correct, but a declaration is *not* an expression. `1+1` is an expression, `a = 1+1` is *not* an expression, but a declaration.

> I would like to know not what the type of main is, but what the type of the whole line is.

This has no type, you simply define a variable with the given expression. The expression `putStrLn "Hello, World!"` has type `IO ()`, since `putStrLn` has type [**`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn).

Comment: It's interesting how @chepner uses the word 'definition' and @[Willem Van Onsem] uses 'declaration'. So everything that is not an expression seems a bit fuzzier... I also found the name 'statement' for non-expressions.

Answer (score 11):

`main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"` is *not* an expression, and thus does not have a type. It's a *definition*, which assigns a value of type `IO ()` (resulting from the evaluation of `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`) to the name `main`.

Following the definition, you can find the type of `main`:

```
> :t main
main :: IO ()
```